# Is it ok to set $_POST variables via php to pass data to your form elements

Tags: php, mysql, post

The scenario:

I've made a long form with lots of inputs and drop down selects, and I've already set it up to check to see if the form has been submitted and come back (due to errors and such) and use php to echo the values back into the appropriate inputs. Something like:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="60" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo trim($_POST['firstname']);} ?>">
```

once the form is submitted it goes into the database. Now i need to design a way for the user to come back and edit the information again, and rather than build an entirely new page to read the data from the db and echo it when the form is first loaded, then echo out the $_POST data if the form is submitted, but returned with errors, I'd like to use the same form and when the page loads, check the db to see if there are any entries for the current logged in user, and if so, set the $_POST variables to the values in the db.

I've written a quick test form and know that this is possible, but was wondering if it was considered improper to set the $_POST variable for this. The test code i wrote looks something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE uid = '$uid'";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            mysql_close(); //no info in db for user. Yet...
        }
        else
        {
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $_POST['submit'] = true; 
            $_POST['firstname'] = $data['firstname']; //and so on...
```

This way I'm able to use the same form without having to modify a ton of code, and build a new page.

Comment: should be fine as long as you sanitize the input. Also, would storing the variables in `$_SESSION` not be another thing to consider aswell, or even a cookie?

Comment: Seems to me as the wrong way around. I'd rather make my forms not depending on the $_POST variable directly, but rather wrap it in an input object. But if you don't care about that, I don't see why you solution would be wrong.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I do not see any problem in manually setting the post variables to serve your purpose, you may get to some logic problems if you are not paying attention, but in the end they are still variables. I think it is the same as you would save the `$_POST` in another variable first and work with it.

The only difference is that `$_POST` is a super global ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php ).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to go this route. It will make the dev time a lot shorter.

Comment: @rmmoul No problem :), but pay attention, you might end up tied up in you own code if you do not structure it well.

Comment: Editing globals is never a good idea. It's one thing to use $_POST, and a whole different thing to edit it. -1.

Answer (score 6):

I would not manually set the $_POST variables.

If somebody else would see your code they will go like: WTF do those values come from???

The `$_POST` superglobal is for post data. Keep it that way.

Comment: Well, the code and the variables are for the programmer to use, just because is a super global and could make your life easier, and you know exactly how it will be working, and in case of failure how to fix, or if it is a small project, I do not see any reason why it should not be set that way... when it comes to the code, everything is fair, as long as it works (and I mean be this to be as well as efficient as optimum)

Comment: @klael `when it comes to the code, everything is fair, as long as it works`. No. You couldn't be more wrong. Coding isn't just about making it work. That mindset is the reason I see lots of ugly unmaintainable , unworkable, undebugable code.

Comment: @PeeHaa I agree with you. One mark of a cowboy programmer is attempting to be clever instead of thinking ahead to when one might have to maintain one's own code, or someone else might have to maintain said code. It's better to value clarity and understandability over cleverness.

Comment: Absolute agree with Brian there, I swear A LOT of the code I have inherited from people would seem to compete at Obfuscated Code contests. Unfortunately, it seems most rife in Web development languages, particularly javascript. Sometimes the flexibility of a language allows people to make horrendous looking code.

Comment: agreed, if you find yourself wanting to change $_POST then you 100% have the wrong solution. also, khael, say what? 0_o are you mad?